# Why is celery not working on Elastic Beans stalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I have an application that runs well with celery on local but when I deploy it into elastic beanstalk, celery seems to shutdown or not run my task. I am using supervisor to run celery.
This is my configuration for supervisord
I also set a global env of C_FORCE_ROOT=true

Error:  `2020-12-21 04:49:56,076 INFO waiting for app, celery-worker to die [2020-12-21 04:49:57,732: DEBUG/MainProcess] removing tasks from inqueue until task handler finished`

```
Unrecoverable error: WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 208, in start
    self.blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 369, in start
    return self.obj.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 318, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/bootsteps.py", line 119, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py", line 599, in start
    c.loop(*c.loop_args())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/worker/loops.py", line 59, in asynloop
    raise WorkerLostError('Could not start worker processes')
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Could not start worker processes
```

---

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
[program:app]
command = gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --worker-class gevent application.app:app
user=root
directory = /usr/src/app/restful
priority = 900
autostart=true
autorestart = true
stopsignal = TERM
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdin_open = true
tty=true

[program:celery-worker]
command= python -m celery worker -A application.libs.celery_config.celery --loglevel=DEBUG --uid=nobody --gid=nogroup
user=root
directory = /usr/src/app/restful
autostart=true
autorestart = false
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdin_open = true
tty=true

[program:celery-beat]
command= python -m celery beat -A application.libs.celery_config.celery --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule  --loglevel=DEBUG
user=root
directory = /usr/src/app/restful
autostart=true
autorestart = false
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
stdin_open = true
tty=true
```